# Kafaka-based Ordering Service configuration

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to create Kafka-based Ordering Service cluster on multiple hosts.

I have two question:

1) Is a shared filesystem required for Kafka / Zookeeper cluster?

2) Which directory should be specified as persistent data?
When ordering service configuration is solo, I think following are target directory. How about Kafka-based Ordering Service?

Orderer: /var/hyperledger/production/orderer, /var/hyperledger/orderer

Peer: /var/hyperledger/production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No.  Neither requires a shared file system.  I'd suggest looking at the Kafka documentation on creating a cluster and/or reading Confluent's excellent documentation on this as well

2) The default value for FileLedger.Location is `/var/hyperledger/production/orderer`.  If you are running the fabric-orderer Docker image than you need to make sure that is mounted as an external volume.

3) Make sure you read http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/kafka.html